# React.js routing keeps rendering my main App regardless of URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am running an issue where, regardless of what URL I am putting into my browser, I keep getting routed to my main page. I've posted the code below for you to take a look, but my goal is to have my browser take me to my drivers.jsx component when the URL is localhost:3000/drivers. Currently, when I go to localhost:3000/drivers, it renders my _app.jsx component instead :(. Can someone help me understand why I can never render the Drivers component (in drivers.jsx) when I am at localhost:3000/drivers?

**index.jsx:**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import MyApp from './_app.jsx';
import Drivers from './drivers.jsx'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from "../routes.js"

class Home extends Component {
   
    render() {

        return (
            <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/drivers' element = {<Drivers />}> </Route>
                <Route exact path='/' element = {<MyApp />}> </Route>                
            </Switch>
        </Router>
        );

    }
}

export default Home;
```

**_app.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useLoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import Map from '../components/map.jsx';
import "../styles/globals.css";

const MyApp = () => {

    const libraries = ['places'];

    const {isLoaded} = useLoadScript({
        googleMapsApiKey: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
        libraries
    });

    if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;

    return (
        <Map />  
    );
    
} 

export default MyApp;
```

**drivers.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Drivers extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <div>TEST</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Drivers;
```

I've tried putting the routing logic inside _app.jsx instead, but that causes an incredible amount of errors. My thought is index.js should host all the routing logic, but it shouldn't keep rendering MyApp instead of Drivers when the route is "localhost:3000/drivers".

Comment: Check your console, I'm certain you've errors. What version of `react-router-dom` is actually installed? RRDv5 doesn't export a `Routes` component, and RRDv6 doesn't export a `Switch` component. The `Route` component you are using the `element` prop which is a RRDv6 prop. Please check by running `npm list react-router-dom` in the terminal in the root project directory and report back.

Answer (score 0):

if your `react-router-dom` version is
`6.4.3`

then the switch component dosen't work try changing code  to this
instead of using `Switch`. wrap `Route` inside `Routes`

```
 <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/drivers' element = {<Drivers />}> />
            <Route exact path='/' element = {<MyApp />}> />                
        </Routes>
    </Router>
```

like this